# MailChimp merge_vars what else is accepted apart from FNAME & LNAME?

Tags: php, mailchimp

I have implemented a very basic sign up using email address+name, although I would now like to add extra data such as Phone Number, Website etc.

My question is where in the [API doc](http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/1.3/) can I find what else is supported apart from FNAME AND LNAME?

At the moment I have:

```
$merge_vars = array(
     'FNAME' => $fname,
     'LNAME' => $lname
);
```

I am using the method `listSubscribe` and this is the information that is provided above:

```
@param array $merge_vars optional merges for the email (FNAME, LNAME, etc.) (see examples below for handling "blank" arrays). Note that a merge field can only hold up to 255 bytes. Also, there are a few "special" keys:
                        string EMAIL set this to change the email address. This is only respected on calls using update_existing or when passed to listUpdateMember()
                        array GROUPINGS Set Interest Groups by Grouping. Each element in this array should be an array containing the "groups" parameter which contains a comma delimited list of Interest Groups to add. Commas in Interest Group names should be escaped with a backslash. ie, "," =&gt; "\," and either an "id" or "name" parameter to specify the Grouping - get from listInterestGroupings()
                        string OPTINIP Set the Opt-in IP fields. <em>Abusing this may cause your account to be suspended.</em> We do validate this and it must not be a private IP address.
                        array MC_LOCATION Set the members geographic location. By default if this merge field exists, we'll update using the optin_ip if it exists. If the array contains LATITUDE and LONGITUDE keys, they will be used. NOTE - this will slow down each subscribe call a bit, especially for lat/lng pairs in sparsely populated areas. Currently our automated background processes can and will overwrite this based on opens and clicks.

                        <strong>Handling Field Data Types</strong> - most fields you can just pass a string and all is well. For some, though, that is not the case...
                        Field values should be formatted as follows:
                        string address For the string version of an Address, the fields should be delimited by <strong>2</strong> spaces. Address 2 can be skipped. The Country should be a 2 character ISO-3166-1 code and will default to your default country if not set
                        array address For the array version of an Address, the requirements for Address 2 and Country are the same as with the string version. Then simply pass us an array with the keys <strong>addr1</strong>, <strong>addr2</strong>, <strong>city</strong>, <strong>state</strong>, <strong>zip</strong>, <strong>country</strong> and appropriate values for each

                        string date use YYYY-MM-DD to be safe. Generally, though, anything strtotime() understands we'll understand - <a href="http://us2.php.net/strtotime" target="_blank">http://us2.php.net/strtotime</a>
                        string dropdown can be a normal string - we <em>will</em> validate that the value is a valid option
                        string image must be a valid, existing url. we <em>will</em> check its existence
                        string multi_choice can be a normal string - we <em>will</em> validate that the value is a valid option
                        double number pass in a valid number - anything else will turn in to zero (0). Note, this will be rounded to 2 decimal places
                        string phone If your account has the US Phone numbers option set, this <em>must</em> be in the form of NPA-NXX-LINE (404-555-1212). If not, we assume an International number and will simply set the field with what ever number is passed in.
                        string website This is a standard string, but we <em>will</em> verify that it looks like a valid URL
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In your list settings you'll find "List Fields and *|MERGE|* Tags". You can add here whatever you want !

You can also add "merge vars" programmatically via the api :

- listMergeVarAdd
- listMergeVarDel
- listMergeVarUpdate

When you add a user in this list via listSubscribe, just use the merge vars as you would do with FNAME

```
$merge_vars = array(
     'FNAME' => $fname,
     'LNAME' => $lname,
     'PHONE' => '010203040506',
     'OTHERCUSTOM' => 'custom field'
);
```

If you need to update user information, just turn update_existing flag to true.

Comment: This is so helpful, something that I could not find from the mailchimp API google group.

Comment: Adding to @Emmanuel Tabard's answer, you can find the OTHERCUSTOM merge tags by logging into your MailChimp account then go to Lists->Your List->Settings->List fields and *|MERGE|* tags.

You can then rename any of your custom fields to use whatever merge tag key you want.

Comment: what if i want to simply remove the value of a field?