# Include Order information in MailChimp Campaign?

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

We already have our customer's Order Information in MailChimp.  It shows on the "E-Commerce" tab of each Contact in the List.

Is it possible to send out a campaign in MailChimp that includes this information?

For example, the customer's most recent Order Number?

Comment: still haven't found a way to use MailChimp e-Commerce data in a Campaign, but I am thinking we can write a program that calls their API and passes the Order data as Custom Merge Fields.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10830311/mailchimp-merge-vars-what-else-is-accepted-apart-from-fname-lname

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, they don't yet have pre-built tool capable of pulling customer/order attributes into a Campaign's content, and at least currently adding any data like this you'd like to dynamically populate in Campaign would require adding any data directly to the list fields and using their merge tags.

- http://kb.mailchimp.com/merge-tags/getting-started-with-merge-tags

They do offer Product centric dynamic content options, if that'd be in any way helpful.

- Use Product Recommendation Content Blocks: http://kb.mailchimp.com/campaigns/content-blocks/use-product-recommendation-content-blocks?utm_source=mc-kb&utm_medium=kb-site&utm_campaign=eepurl
- Merge tags for products: http://kb.mailchimp.com/merge-tags/all-the-merge-tags-cheat-sheet#Merge-Tags-for-Product-Recommendations

Answer (score 0):

You can optionally store merge fields associated with each list recipient:

http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/merge-fields/

You could create a custom merge field for "MOSTRECENTORDER" for each customer, and then reference it within templates using *|MOSTRECENTORDER|*

Comment: yes, but it would be empty right?  how to get the data into the Merge field?

Comment: You would need some sort of tool to insert it.

I haven't worked in the e-commerce section of the Mailchimp API, so I'm not sure if there is a way to trigger an HTTP POST when a new order is created.

If so, you could have a simple server that listens for new order POSTs and then sends the above API call to MC.

If not, you could write something that periodically (every minute? 10 sec?) polls http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/ecommerce/stores/orders/# for new orders, then sends the merge fields call